# Is it safe to mutate values in a HashBiMap?

Tags: java, guava, hashcode, bimap

In my code I'd like to have a

```
HashBiMap<T1, HashSet<T2>> bimap;
```

Is it OK to mutate values in a bimap? When I use `bimap.inverse()`, won't it lead to the same `hashCode()`-related issues it leads with a HashMap containing mutable keys?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to have exactly the same problems - but surely it's trivial for you to test this anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You end up with exactly the same problems as you normally get when mutating an object which is used as a key in a hash-based map, and this is easily demonstrated:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.google.common.collect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashBiMap<String, HashSet<String>> bimap = HashBiMap.create();
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        bimap.put("foo", set);
        System.out.println(bimap.inverse().get(set)); // foo
        set.add("bar");
        System.out.println(bimap.inverse().get(set)); // null 
    }
}
```

So no, it's not safe to do this. Ideally, you should use an immutable type as the key to completely prevent this from happening rather than relying on being careful with when you mutate the objects in question.

Comment: I elaborated more about BiMap usage and creating immutable value Set by JDK8 collector chain in following blogpost: http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2017/02/playing-with-java-8-collectors.html